# How to query post's hot score? My query is slow in postgresql

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I'm making a community web app.

Below code works fine with small local test data.

But with many data (more then 10k) this works very slow.

Here is postgresql query plan

```
"Limit  (cost=6653.10..6653.13 rows=10 width=641) (actual time=355.355..355.357 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, title, content, like_count, comment_count, view_count, scrap_count, deleted, has_img, has_video, created_at, updated_at, author_id, forum_id, prefix_id, width, height, link_id, ((log((GREATEST(like_count, 1))::double precision) + (date_part(' (...)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=6653.10..6903.41 rows=100123 width=641) (actual time=355.353..355.353 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Output: id, title, content, like_count, comment_count, view_count, scrap_count, deleted, has_img, has_video, created_at, updated_at, author_id, forum_id, prefix_id, width, height, link_id, ((log((GREATEST(like_count, 1))::double precision) + (date_ (...)"
"        Sort Key: ((log((GREATEST(tc_posts.like_count, 1))::double precision) + (date_part('epoch'::text, age(tc_posts.created_at, now())) / '45000'::double precision))) DESC, tc_posts.created_at DESC, tc_posts.id DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.tc_posts  (cost=0.00..4489.48 rows=100123 width=641) (actual time=0.029..188.306 rows=100109 loops=1)"
"              Output: id, title, content, like_count, comment_count, view_count, scrap_count, deleted, has_img, has_video, created_at, updated_at, author_id, forum_id, prefix_id, width, height, link_id, (log((GREATEST(like_count, 1))::double precision) + ( (...)"
"              Filter: (NOT tc_posts.deleted)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 24"
"Planning time: 0.194 ms"
"Execution time: 355.427 ms"
```

It takes more than 300 ms in query plan.
How can I optimize the below query??

```sql
SELECT *, 
       LOG(GREATEST(like_count, 1)) + EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(tc_posts.created_at, NOW()))/45000 AS hot 
FROM "tc_posts" 
WHERE "deleted" = FALSE
ORDER BY "hot" DESC, 
         "created_at" DESC, 
         "id" DESC,
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your data so just a few hints:

- Try to set higher work_mem - add command like this `set work_mem = '128MB';` before `EXPLAIN` and test different work_mem settings for a session. But if this is usable depends on how many memory you have and how many sessions you use.
- `SELECT *` is always performance killer unless you really need all columns.
- I can see `Seq Scan on public.tc_posts ... Filter: (NOT tc_posts.deleted)` in output - consider adding index on `tc_posts.deleted`
- When PostgreSQL opens new session there is some delay so maybe you could use pgbouncer with pooling by transaction - it will save you some mimiseconds for every connection